# Raphael & Href Target

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have link, done as text with href and target parameter in my drawing.
I can see the TARGET being present, but still after clicking on the link, it opens in the current window despite Target being set to "_blank". My browser is current Chrome 23.whatever
Here is what I see in the page:

```
<a style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" xlink:href="http://www.google.com" xlink:target="_blank">
<text style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: start; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14pt; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial; opacity: 1;" x="275.8000030517578" y="157.31666564941406" text-anchor="start" font="14pt &quot;Arial&quot;" stroke="none" fill="#0070c0" opacity="1">
<tspan style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
This is the link to Google
</tspan></text></a>
```

Comment: probably I should add xlink:show="new" instead of target

Answer (score 0):

It's just [target](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#AElementTargetAttribute) (no xlink) although there is an xlink:show attribute.

Comment: When I check the source in the developer tools in chrome, it shows is at normal a-href-target, but when I select Edit HTML, it shows as xlink:target

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome, perhaps you should report it. Does it work as you expect in Opera or Firefox?

Comment: It works for me on Firefox as long as the xlink: is removed. Try safe mode perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Old thread I know - but in case you get here looking for how to add a target attribute to a link in Raphael to get links to open in a new window/tab:

```
bxtxt.attr({"href":"https://www.example.com","target":"new"});
```

This will render as:

```
<a xlink:href="https://www.example.com" xlink:show="new">etc</a>
```

**Note:** that in the chrome inspector devtools, it will look like:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com" show="new">etc</a>
```

and not as you may expect:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank">etc</a>
```

**Update**:
Since the xlink:show is marked as [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:show) it is wise to add:

```
 $(bxtxt.node).parent().attr("target","_blank");
```

This adds the target to the a link for forward compatibility

```
<a xlink:href="https://www.example.com" xlink:show="new" target="_blank">
```